# reading specific cell in csv using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
patient_id, age_in_years,   CENSUS_REGION,  URBAN_RURAL_STATUS

11511,  7   Northeast,  Urban,

9882613,    73, South,  Urban,

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,

32190339,   49, West,   Urban,
32190339,   49, West,   Urban,

.....
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = 0)
```

which gives the following output:

```
patient_id age_in_years CENSUS_REGION URBAN_RURAL_STATUS  YEAR  MONTH  

11511                  7     Northeast              Urban  2011      6   
9882613               73         South              Urban  2011      7   
32190339              49          West              Urban  2011      8   
32190339              49          West              Urban  2011      8   
32190339              49          West              Urban  2011      8   
32190339              49          West              Urban  2011      8   
32190339              49          West              Urban  2011      8   
32190339              49          West              Urban  2011      8
...
```

I can get a specific column, e.g. CENSUS_REGION, by

```
print(df['CENSUS_REGION'])
```

but I want to grab specific cells in the CSV. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Which specific cell?

Comment: what do you want to extract from your example input?

Comment: any specific cell, e.g. the age in years associated with a specific patient id, say 11511.

Comment: You mean `print(df.loc[11511]["age_in_years"])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting the `column`, you can subscript using the `index` to get the specific value for that *cell*.

Example , in your case, your first column seems to be `patient_id` , so that is the index, you can index using that.

Example -

```
print(df['CENSUS_REGION'][11511])
```

The above would get the data of `CENSUS_REGION` column for the patient with id - 11511 .

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]:
             age_in_years    CENSUS_REGION   URBAN_RURAL_STATUS
patient_id
11511                   7        Northeast                Urban
9882613                73            South                Urban
32190339               49             West                Urban
32190339               49             West                Urban
32190339               49             West                Urban
32190339               49             West                Urban

In [33]: df['   CENSUS_REGION']
Out[33]:
patient_id
11511          Northeast
9882613            South
32190339            West
32190339            West
32190339            West
32190339            West
Name:    CENSUS_REGION, dtype: object

In [34]: df['   CENSUS_REGION'][11511]
Out[34]: '   Northeast'
```

Please note, I had to use lots of spaces, since the csv was messed up, but `'   CENSUS_REGION'` is just the column name.